# Is FedEx shipping api works in India Domestic

Tags: php, fedex

I tried to implement fedex api to calculate the cost of shipping betwnn to zip codes of a country. It is working fine for USA. It is also working from USA to other country(tried for IN and AU). But when I tried it for two zip codes from India or Australia as shipper and recipient address. It is giving below error :-

```
The transaction returned an Error.
Severity: ERROR
Source: crs
Code: 691
Message: The PurposeOfShipmentType is null, empty or invalid.
LocalizedMessage: The PurposeOfShipmentType is null, empty or invalid.
```

Don't know what is the issue. I checked the value for PurposeOfShipmentType in wsdl file it is showing below xml code :-

```
First occurrence
<xs:element name="Purpose" type="ns:PurposeOfShipmentType" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation>The reason for the shipment. Note: SOLD is not a valid purpose for a Proforma Invoice.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>

second occurrence
<xs:simpleType name="PurposeOfShipmentType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="GIFT"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="NOT_SOLD"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="PERSONAL_EFFECTS"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="REPAIR_AND_RETURN"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="SAMPLE"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="SOLD"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

Don't understanding what should be the value. Below is array which I am sending into $client ->getRates($request) function

```
$request = Array
(
[WebAuthenticationDetail] => Array
    (
        [UserCredential] => Array
            (
                [Key] => *******
                [Password] => *******
            )

    )

[ClientDetail] => Array
    (
        [AccountNumber] => *****
        [MeterNumber] => *****
    )

[TransactionDetail] => Array
    (
        [CustomerTransactionId] =>  *** Rate Available Services Request using PHP ***
    )

[Version] => Array
    (
        [ServiceId] => crs
        [Major] => 16
        [Intermediate] => 0
        [Minor] => 0
    )

[ReturnTransitAndCommit] => 1
[RequestedShipment] => Array
    (
        [DropoffType] => REGULAR_PICKUP
        [ShipTimestamp] => 2014-10-03T11:37:53+02:00
        [Shipper] => Array
            (
                [Address] => Array
                    (
                        [StreetLines] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 10 Fed Ex Pkwy
                            )

                        [City] => Memphis
                        [StateOrProvinceCode] => 
                        [PostalCode] => 110016
                        [CountryCode] => IN
                    )

            )

        [Recipient] => Array
            (
                [Address] => Array
                    (
                        [StreetLines] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 13450 Farmcrest Ct
                            )

                        [City] => Herndon
                        [StateOrProvinceCode] => 
                        [PostalCode] => 302015
                        [CountryCode] => IN
                    )

            )

        [ShippingChargesPayment] => Array
            (
                [PaymentType] => SENDER
                [Payor] => Array
                    (
                        [ResponsibleParty] => Array
                            (
                                [AccountNumber] => 510087500
                                [Contact] => 
                                [Address] => Array
                                    (
                                        [CountryCode] => IN
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [PackageCount] => 2
        [RequestedPackageLineItems] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [SequenceNumber] => 1
                        [GroupPackageCount] => 1
                        [Weight] => Array
                            (
                                [Value] => 2
                                [Units] => LB
                            )

                        [Dimensions] => Array
                            (
                                [Length] => 10
                                [Width] => 10
                                [Height] => 3
                                [Units] => IN
                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [SequenceNumber] => 2
                        [GroupPackageCount] => 1
                        [Weight] => Array
                            (
                                [Value] => 5
                                [Units] => LB
                            )

                        [Dimensions] => Array
                            (
                                [Length] => 20
                                [Width] => 20
                                [Height] => 10
                                [Units] => IN
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

)

Comment: It tells you what is wrong. `PurposeOfShipmentType` and `PurposeOfShipmentType` are either; null, empty, or invalid.

Comment: I have edited question for your comment. I checked the value of PurposeOfShipmentType but don't know what should it be.

Comment: And what are you sending?

Comment: In Shipper zip code of India's one city and for Recipient India's another city's zip code with country code IN
It is working fine for International shipping and for USA cities

Comment: In your request, what is the value of `PurposeOfShipmentType`?

Comment: I don't set it in my request file it was not in the api file itself it is only in the wsdl file and I posted the code in question

Comment: Can you provide your XML before it's sent? Remove the sensitive data before, though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62395/discussion-between-bharat-maheshwari-and-).

Comment: ---1: It literally says right there in the error message what the problem is. Reading is an important skill for a programmer.

Comment: We can read error messages but how to solve the error for that this forum made. reading and problem solving are two different things @Lightness

Comment: @BharatMaheshwari: Reading is required for problem solving. You need to do more than just read the error message then ask for help. You need to read the error message _and then read research materials that tell you about it_. i.e. do some work. And this is not a forum.

Answer (score 6):

In order for the India to India domestic shipping to work you need to add in a `PurposeOfShipment` type to the request. This line is not standard in Magento's code for Fedex shipping. That line will be added into `CustomsClearanceDetail` header as a child under `CommercialInvoice` then a line under that is `Purpose`which can have any value that `PurposeOfShipment` has.

Here is an example of the request I used that returned proper shipping estimates for India to India shipping.

```
'CustomsClearanceDetail' => array(
     'CommercialInvoice' => array(
       'Purpose' => "SOLD"
    )
),
```

Comment: how to do in opencart? do u hav any idea?

Comment: what is your exact issue?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, Fedex's Test Account doesn't return India specific info. Unless until its certified by the Fedex team and they provide you with the Production Key, you might not get the Rates aggreed for your account. Please do correct me if my understanding is wrong